# When one condition is satisfied, I don't want the other if condition to be conducted (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    def creation_time_of_files(folder_path, selected_date):
        
        for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            # print(file_path)

            if os.path.isfile(file_path) and filename.endswith(".txt"):
                creation_time = os.path.getctime(file_path)
                formatted_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(
                    creation_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                
                if selected_date==date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):
                    if formatted_time==selected_date: 
                     with open(file_path, 'r') as file: #when there's today's diary
                        content = file.read()
                        file_window = tk.Toplevel(new_window2)
                        lab = tk.Label(file_window, text=str(content))
                        lab.pack()
                        
                    elif formatted_time!=selected_date: #there's no today's diary
                        
                        real_diarypage()
                 
                if selected_date!=date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") and formatted_time==selected_date:
                    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
                        content = file.read()
                        file_window = tk.Toplevel(new_window2)
                        
                        lab = tk.Label(file_window, text=str(content))
                        lab.pack()
                        return content
```

So a file will go through the condition "if formatted_time==selected_date", and then it'll go out of the whole if loop. Then, another file, which is written before today, will go through the condition "elif formatted_time!=selected_date" and real_diarypage() will be done. real_diarypage() is a function of writing a new diary.

I want today's diary pops up when I click the calendar. However, although when there's today's diary, writing a new diary window pops up. So I want to make the code as :
when there's today's diary:
show today's diary

when there isn't today's diary:
write today's diary

How should I change my code? Should I change the whole algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do but maybe you need `elif`. OR simply use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: _when there's today's diary_ What does that mean exactly?  Does this mean **if a file with a certain name exists**?

Comment: It means when there's a file with written time that is today